# Flask: Keep track of background thread's progress

Tags: python, flask

I have a web app where background processing is done like this

```
@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    @copy_current_request_context
    def do_work():
        bar()
    thread.start_new_thread(do_work, ())
```

Inside that process I set session['progress'] and from the webpage I use AJAX to retrieve session['progress']. However, I've found that the session doesn't persist to the bg thread only the request context does. So... I'm not sure what to do.

I'm using KVSessionExtension so the sessions are stored on the server. Is there a way of storing the progress per user session or am I going to have to store the progress globally? 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?  Also, what does `copy_current_request_context` look like?

Comment: That's a Flask decorator that makes the request context available to a bg thread.

Comment: What happens if you put some data in the session in your `foo` route?  For example, if you set `session['progress'] = 0` in `foo` and then start *updating* it in `do_work` / `bar`?  Flask-KVSession may not be serializing a session for you because nothing in the session has yet been modified ... but that's just a guess after looking through the code.